# Display Microsoft Thumbnails binary image

Tags: javascript, thumbnails

I'm trying the Microsoft Cognitive Services, particularly the Thumbnails piece. I have a fairly simple code to send an image file and read the response. My issue is that I haven't been able to display the resulting thumbnail. I tried encoding the "response" but still no image is rendered.

Here's the function that I'm using:

```
var apiUrl = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/generateThumbnail?width=175&height=104&smartCropping=true";

$('#btn').click(function () {
var file = document.getElementById('filename').files[0];
$.ajax({
    url: apiUrl,
    beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
    },
    type: "POST",
    data: file,
    processData: false
})
.done(function (response) {
    $('#image').attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response);
})
.fail(function (error) {
    $("#response").text(error.getAllResponseHeaders());
});
```

});

If I print the response the data looks like this:

"%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%00%10JFIF%00%01%01%01%00`%00`%00%00%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%00C%00%08%06%06%07%06%05%08%07%07%07%08%0C%14%0C%0B%0B%0C%19%12%13%0F%14%1D%1A%1F%1E%1D%1A%1C%1C $.' ","

Thank you in advance.